# Sum array of objects with Lodash

Tags: arrays, object, sum, lodash

I'd like to sum objects from array, I've been searching and testing different things founds around there, using Lodash or not, without any success.

Here is the data array, there is 5 elements but it could be less or more. The properties will always be the same, but there could be a lot more.

```js
const data = [
    {
        from: "2019-10-15",
        stats: [
            {
                options: {
                    width: 15,
                    height: 20,
                    borders: 35,
                    removable: 5
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        from: "2019-10-16",
        stats: [
            {
                options: {
                    width: 22,
                    height: 18,
                    borders: 10,
                    removable: 0
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        from: "2019-10-17",
        stats: [
            {
                options: {
                    width: 0,
                    height: 15,
                    borders: 15,
                    removable: 0
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        from: "2019-10-18",
        stats: [
            {
                options: {
                    width: 20,
                    height: 20,
                    borders: 10,
                    removable: 5,
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        from: "2019-10-19",
        stats: [
            {
                options: {
                    width: 0,
                    height: 10,
                    borders: 0,
                    removable: 30
                }
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

The expected result is the sum of each array element `stats[0].options` properties:

```js
const sum = {
    width: 57,
    height: 83,
    borders: 70,
    removable: 40
}
```

I know it's definitely not complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Use `_.map()` to get the `options`, then combine the objects using [`_.mergeWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mergeWith), and use [`_.add()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#add) as the customizer.

```js
const data = [{"from":"2019-10-15","stats":[{"options":{"width":15,"height":20,"borders":35,"removable":5}}]},{"from":"2019-10-16","stats":[{"options":{"width":22,"height":18,"borders":10,"removable":0}}]},{"from":"2019-10-17","stats":[{"options":{"width":0,"height":15,"borders":15,"removable":0}}]},{"from":"2019-10-18","stats":[{"options":{"width":20,"height":20,"borders":10,"removable":5}}]},{"from":"2019-10-19","stats":[{"options":{"width":0,"height":10,"borders":0,"removable":30}}]}];

const result = _.mergeWith({}, ..._.map(data, 'stats[0].options'), _.add);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

If you use [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) you can create a function using `_.flow()`, and replace `_.mergeWith` with `_.mergeAllWith()`:

```js
const { flow, map, mergeAllWith, add } = _;

const fn = flow(
  map('stats[0].options'),
  mergeAllWith(add)
);

const data = [{"from":"2019-10-15","stats":[{"options":{"width":15,"height":20,"borders":35,"removable":5}}]},{"from":"2019-10-16","stats":[{"options":{"width":22,"height":18,"borders":10,"removable":0}}]},{"from":"2019-10-17","stats":[{"options":{"width":0,"height":15,"borders":15,"removable":0}}]},{"from":"2019-10-18","stats":[{"options":{"width":20,"height":20,"borders":10,"removable":5}}]},{"from":"2019-10-19","stats":[{"options":{"width":0,"height":10,"borders":0,"removable":30}}]}];

const result = fn(data);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done through vanill JavaScript. Just use `reduce` and `foreach` methods:

```js
const data = [
    {
        from: "2019-10-15",
        stats: [
            {
                options: {
                    width: 15,
                    height: 20,
                    borders: 35,
                    removable: 5
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        from: "2019-10-16",
        stats: [
            {
                options: {
                    width: 22,
                    height: 18,
                    borders: 10,
                    removable: 0
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        from: "2019-10-17",
        stats: [
            {
                options: {
                    width: 0,
                    height: 15,
                    borders: 15,
                    removable: 0
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        from: "2019-10-18",
        stats: [
            {
                options: {
                    width: 20,
                    height: 20,
                    borders: 10,
                    removable: 5,
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        from: "2019-10-19",
        stats: [
            {
                options: {
                    width: 0,
                    height: 10,
                    borders: 0,
                    removable: 30
                }
            }
        ]
    }
];

const result = data.reduce((a, {stats}) => {
    stats.forEach(({options}) => {
        for (const key in options) {
            a[key] = a[key] || 0;
            a[key] += options[key];
        }
    });

    return a;
}, {})

console.log(result);
```

The vanilla JS code looks like this:

```
const result = data.reduce((a, {stats}) => {
    stats.forEach(({options}) => {
        for (const key in options) {
            a[key] = a[key] || 0;
            a[key] += options[key];
        }
    });

    return a;
}, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to do this with a `reduce` and nested `forEach`, but a bit more straightforward:

```js
const data = [
    {
        from: "2019-10-15",
        stats: [
            {
                options: {
                    width: 15,
                    height: 20,
                    borders: 35,
                    removable: 5
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        from: "2019-10-16",
        stats: [
            {
                options: {
                    width: 22,
                    height: 18,
                    borders: 10,
                    removable: 0
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        from: "2019-10-17",
        stats: [
            {
                options: {
                    width: 0,
                    height: 15,
                    borders: 15,
                    removable: 0
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        from: "2019-10-18",
        stats: [
            {
                options: {
                    width: 20,
                    height: 20,
                    borders: 10,
                    removable: 5,
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        from: "2019-10-19",
        stats: [
            {
                options: {
                    width: 0,
                    height: 10,
                    borders: 0,
                    removable: 30
                }
            }
        ]
    }
];

let result = _.reduce(data, (acc, value) =>{
      // our nested options object
      const options = value.stats[0].options;
      
      _.forEach(options, (optionValue, optionKey) =>{
        // if we know about this key already, then add optionValue to it
        // if not, this will be our first value for that key
        acc[optionKey] = !!acc[optionKey] ? acc[optionKey] + optionValue : optionValue;
      })
      
      return acc;
}, {})

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```